# Why is the induced homomorphism an injection?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am reading Hatcher's Algebraic Topology. One of the propositions says that if a space X retracts to a subspace A, the the homomorphism i# induced by the inclusion i: A --> X is injective.

It is proved as follows:
If r:X --> A is a retraction, then ri = 1. Thus r#i# = 1, which implies i# is injective. I am a little lost on why i# is injective. Can anybody explain why r#i# implies i# is injective?

Comment: Take x and y such that i#(x)=i#(y) and apply r#.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $g\circ f$ is injective, for any functions $f, g$, then $f$ is injective. Proof: if $f(x)=f(y)$, then $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$. Since $g\circ f$ is injective, we conclude that $x=y$, so indeed $f$ is injective as claimed.

Comment: So simple! Don't know how I didn't see this, thank you Alex!

Comment: There's an analogous fact about $g$ being surjective, by the way